# Como cambiar el formato de fecha (timestamp) en Laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Quisiera cambiar el formato de timestamp para poder ver si me agrega un usuario al creármelo con la bdd de Oracle. En contexto, el formato que me manda es Y-m-d y en oracle es de formato D-m-y. Si alguien podría ayudarme, se lo agradecería!

Comment: Si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

En tu modelo puedes utilizar la propiedad `$dateFormat` para cambiar el formato por el que tu desees, por ejemplo:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    protected $dateFormat = 'D-m-y H:i:s';
}
```

Comment: Ahora lo que me dice es: se ha encontrado un carácter no numérico donde se esperaba uno numérico Position : 107 y me da este formato: Thu-02-22 10:26:48,0 en vez de ponerme 24-02-22 10:26:48,0

Comment: El formato cambió tal como lo configuraste, ¿De dónde viene ese error? Tal vez de la base de datos

Comment: @LautaroRodriguez Si lo que esperas es el número del día entonces el formato que pusiste en tu pregunta está mal, D representa día de la semana utilizando 3 letras, yo hice el ejemplo con el formato que tu mostraste. [Aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date_format.asp) puedes ver la documentación del formato

Comment: Exacto, pregunte mal. Ahora que lo vi, lo pude solucionar. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!!

Comment: @LautaroRodriguez, no hay de qué. Si la respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas.